# How to increase the voltage of a power source?

Tags: voltage, amperage

We have a USB 5V 3A. How can I increase this voltage to 12V with losing current level? I need 12V 1A. I need a circuit drawing which I can assemble for this.

How to preserve power (15 W), and not current, at higher voltage?

Comment: Have you heard of boost regulators?

Comment: @winny you must have misread. OP wants to convert 5V 3A (15W) to 12V 1A (12W). So at least theoretically possible, though efficiency may be an issue.

Comment: Try a universal automatic buck & boost. Any input, any output, quasi ...

Comment: @jcaron Dang it. I have indeed. Boost converter it is.

Comment: The question should have asked how to preserve power (15 W), and not current, at higher voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka "Have you heard of boost regulators?" Nope. Thank you, this is answer that I have sought.

Comment: @Antonio51 "buck & boost". Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a monolithic boost regulator. Although buying a 'chip' removes a bunch of problems, the construction has to be done well, this is not something you can build in a sloppy manner (in particular the loop areas have to be minimized in both switch closed and open states). Also, use exactly the inductor part number recommended unless you really know what you are doing. Here is one possibility, there are dozens of others:

[image]

This [chip](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Diodes%20PDFs/PAM2421,22,23.pdf) has a ~5A switch so it will be fine producing 12V/1A with a 5V input (not a 3.6V input).

Efficiency is claimed > 85% at 5V in/ 12V 1A out, and  you only need 80% so that should be just okay. Note that you're already hitting the minimum efficiency with a 4.5V input so don't add any unnecessary resistance to the USB circuit.

[image]